# Javascript play audio when loaded

Tags: javascript, html, audio, slider, volume

so I have a code for volume slider. What it does is that it plays sound when you have changed volume after loading the slider. For example if default value of the slider is 50 it wont play sound right after loading the audio file, you need to change value to higher or lower so sound can come out. So I need help with JavaScript. What can I do so it starts playing the sound whenever is loaded?

Full code : https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FQZVZUX36JFD

JS:

```
$("#volume").slider({
min: 0,
max: 100,
value: 50,
    range: "min",
slide: function(event, ui) {
    setVolume(ui.value / 100);
}
});

var myMedia = document.createElement('audio');
$('#player').append(myMedia);
myMedia.id = "myMedia";

playAudio('http://listen.shoutcast.com/newfm64aac-', 0);

function playAudio(fileName, myVolume) {
        myMedia.src = fileName;
        myMedia.setAttribute('loop', 'loop');
    setVolume(myVolume);
    myMedia.play();
}

function setVolume(myVolume) {
var myMedia = document.getElementById('myMedia');
myMedia.volume = myVolume;
}
```

Comment: Can you update your full code link. It's not giving me any code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the initial volume to zero with this call:

```
playAudio('http://listen.shoutcast.com/newfm64aac-', 0);
```

To have it load at a default of 50 your call should be:

```
playAudio('http://listen.shoutcast.com/newfm64aac-', 50);
```

Comment: when I set it to 50 then no sound comes at all

Comment: What if you set the volume to .5? I just noticed that the slider adjust sends it in as /100

Answer (score 2):

[Google recently released a browser update that prevents initial playing or autoplaying of media elements](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) (Note: not the solution for this answer, but a potential solution for similar cases.)